# How to Implement custom role provider with bootstrap template sitemap using mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Please i will appreciate if anyone could send me a link or show How to Implement custom role provider with bootstrap template sitemap using mvc 5.

Comment: What does bootstrap have to do with a role provider?  I don't understand the question.

Comment: i am using a bootstrap html template i bought from Themeforest, on a normal web forms, .not sitemap would have been used. i want to be able to show and hide some menu items based on user sign in role. I have done it in MVC 4, but was still using sitemap and the same approach does not work for me in MVC 5, i guess there would have been a different approach in handling it.

Answer (score 0):

To implement custom roles:

**If you haven't enabled migrations**

1. Go to: Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console;
2. `Enable-Migrations`, it will open the Configuration.cs, if don't open, search in folder Migrations;

**Then**

On Configuration search for Seed and use this code inside the seed:

```
    context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(r => r.Name,
        new IdentityRole { Name = "Role1" },
        new IdentityRole { Name = "Role2" },
        new IdentityRole { Name = "Role3" }
        );

    var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
    UserManager.AddToRole("Put User ID here", "Role1");
```

And `Add-Migration <name>` and `Update-Database`

**To use the roles in order to allow the access only for a specific role:**

On the controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles="User")]
```

**If you want to allow multiple roles**

```
[Authorize(Roles="User, Administrator")]
```

**If you want some conditions**

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{ 
       //execute x
} else {
       //execute y
}
```

**==  EDIT  ==**

How to show/hide menus (more specific)

On MVC template menus are on _Layout.cshtml Page, on Views/Shared.

I'll paste here a example of normal menu and admin menu with more options:

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Alerts", "Alerts", "Alerts")</li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">BackOffice<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("User Activity", "Index", "UserAccess")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Hospitals", "Index", "Hospitals")</li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Management Tables</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Exam Type", "Index", "Exams")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Medical Specialities", "Index", "MedicalSpecialities")</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
        else
        {
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("User Log", "Index", "UserAccess")</li>
            </ul>
        }
```

As you can see, the `@if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) { } else { }` is the condition that show X menu or Y menu.

Comment: How do i hide and show menus with this? Thanks though

Comment: Ok, take a look to my answer now!

Comment: Thanks Denis V, does it mean i will have to hard code role name for Role1,Role2 and Role3, also User ID would be stored in a session variable, How can i pass it to where you have "Put User ID here" in the Configuration.cs file. Thanks

Comment: You need to go to your Database, table AspNetUsers and copy the ID of the user you want to add to role

Comment: I don't want to use ASPNetUsers table, i have created a table called users, can i still use this table to accomplished this?

Comment: I am using database first approach, I am having immigration issues, could this still work for that? if yes, please can you show an example? Thanks

Comment: It does not matter, show errors you are getting by editing your question

Comment: Ok, do i have to hard code the user IDs and their roles from my users and roles tables? also where  am i going to use related values from UsersInRoles table. thanks

Comment: yes, if you want something more complex you may create a page specific to add users to roles

Comment: In this case there will be no need for UsersInRoles table right?

Comment: Roles system need 3 tables: Users, Roles [id, name] AND UsersInRoles [UserID and RoleID]

Comment: how do i use usersInRoles in this example?

Comment: You don't use it, as I wrote, you use it: `if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))`

Comment: On the Configuration.cs file, is there anyway i can pass user IDs and Roles as list items to it?

Comment: Hello Denis, i still haven't been able to implement this, please could you help me out, i am using mvc 5 database first approach.

Comment: so, you want to add a list of users to a list of roles? you only can add a list of users to 1 role (or if you want, a list of roles to 1 user). if you still ned to use 2 lists, tell me the conditions to the program know if it will need to add user1 to role3 or not, for example

Comment: My challenge is: i have a custom login form and customs users table that has username and password, i also have Roles and UsersInRoles tables, how do i use this in the Configuration.cs file?

Comment: My challenge is: i have a custom login form and customs users table that with username and password, i also have Roles and UsersInRoles tables, how do i use this in the Configuration.cs file? my roles are: admin, staff and users. the users role has more than 1000 users, five staff users, and three admin users. Please kindly help, i have been researching on this for more than six months now, i can do this in mvc4, but the approach i use in mvc4 doesn't work in mvc5. Please help. Thanks in advance